# How to use single view for several router?

Tags: node.js, express, view, routes

I have the following:

```
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('layout.jade');
});

router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
    res.render('layout.jade');
});
```

As you can see from the code above I use single `layout.jade` for two routes. How to combine it with single route definition to remove duplicate code? Something like the following:

```
router.get('/|/about', function(req, res) {
  res.render('layout.jade');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd keep the routes separate. Either redirect to the other route or combine your callback.

```
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', index);

router.get('/about', index);

function index(req, res) {
    res.render('layout.jade');
}
```

If you really must do this, you can use a regex.

```
router.get(/\/(about)?/, function(req, res) {
  res.render('layout.jade');
});
```

Comment: Nice solution but I have no separate rouer function from route defenition

Comment: Then make one. It's without a doubt the most elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I thought is possible to write somwthing like thhis: `router.get(['/', '/about'], function (req, res) {});`

Comment: @Erik That was a possibility in Express 3, but is now deprecated.

Comment: Why? It looks very useful